# Upgrading elementary OS to Freya

Tags: upgrade, elementary-os, distributions

I have elementary OS Luna and I want to upgrade it to Freya.  As I did past times in Ubuntu, I've waited to the package manager to notify me the new version is out and to upgrade the OS but Elementary simply does not do this.

I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but nothing happened.  Which source should I inport to upgrade the entire system?

Thanks!!

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment elementary isn't providing an upgrade path from update manager since results are mixed. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. You can try:

1. Back up EVERYTHING.
2. [Make a Freya install disk](https://elementary.io/docs/installation).
3. Boot from the install disk and select the "upgrade" option.

However, as I said, results may vary. It's always recommended to perform a clean install. An upgrade will not give you the exact same experience as a clean install since it won't overwrite your personal settings. This is important for new features like tab naming in Terminal.

Comment: I didn't know Elementary does not provides an upgrade path from update manager.  I thought I was missing a line in my sources.list file.  Thanks!